# Preserving anchors and aliases in YAML with Python

Tags: python, yaml, cross-reference, ruamel.yaml

I'm editing a large YAML document in Python with extensive anchors and aliases.  I'd like to be able to determine how the anchor is derived based on data from the node it references.

For instance the node has a 'name' field and I'd like the anchor to be the value of that field rather than a random id number.

Is this possible with PyYAML or ruamel.yaml?

Comment: What do you mean with how the anchor is derived? When dumping a data-structure, PyYAML and ruamel.yaml check if a particular complex object (i.e. not a primtive like integer, string) was already dumped and creates an alias if it was. One of the things ruamel.yaml does is keep the original anchor name attached to that complex structure, so it can reuse it. But there is no list of references, there is one object with multiple paths through the datastructure to that object. You'll have to walk the tree to find all the references just like the dumper does.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I'd like to be able to modify that anchor on the initial load.  Is this only possible by looking at the Events level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things to keep in mind:

- YAML has no fields. I assume that that is your interpretation of keys in a mapping, so that you want an anchor associated with a mapping to be the same as the value for the key '`name`'
- During load time the event created when encountering an anchor doesn't know about whether it is an anchor on a scalar, sequence or mapping. Let alone that it could access the value for '`name`'.
- Changing the anchor during load is tricky, as you have to keep track of aliases referring to the original anchor (and map them to its new value)
- In PyYAML the anchor name gets created during `dump`-ing, so you would have to hook into that when using PyYAML. You can do the same with `ruamel.yaml`
- Only `ruamel.yaml` has the capability to preserve an anchor on round-trip. I.e. if you can have the anchor to be persistent, even if the value for the key '`name`' changes (assuming you test e.g. on the default generated form `idNNNN`)

When you use `ruamel.yaml` you can recursively walk the data-structure, keeping track of nodes already visited (in case a child contains an ancestor) and when encountering a `ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap`, set the anchor (currently the attribute with the value of `ruamel.yaml.comments.Anchor.attrib` i.e. `_yaml_anchor`). Untested code:

```
if isinstance(x, ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap):
    if 'name' in x:
        x.yaml_set_anchor(x['name'])
```

If you have a YAML document that you can round-trip you can hook into the representer:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.representer import RoundTripRepresenter

yaml_str = """\
# data = [dict(a=1, b=2, name='mydata'), dict(c=3)]
# data.append(data[0])
- &id001
  a: 1
  b: 2
  name: mydata
- c: 3
- *id001
"""

class MyRTR(RoundTripRepresenter):
    def represent_mapping(self, tag, mapping, flow_style=None):
        if 'name' in mapping:
            # if not isinstance(mapping, ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap):
            #     mapping = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap(mapping)
        mapping.yaml_set_anchor(mapping['name'])

            mapping.yaml_set_anchor(mapping['name'])
        return RoundTripRepresenter.represent_mapping(
            self, tag, mapping, flow_style=flow_style)


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.Representer = MyRTR
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
# data = [dict(a=1, b=2, name='mydata'), dict(c=3)]
# data.append(data[0])
- &mydata a: 1
  b: 2
  name: mydata
- c: 3
- *mydata
```

But note that this assumes that you loaded the data and that all `dict`s are actually `CommentedMap`s under the hood. If that is not the case (i.e. you added normal `dict`s, then uncomment the two lines doing the conversion.

Comment: Thank you this is a very detailed answer and helps a lot in figuring out whether what I want is feasible or not.  And thanks for your work on ruamel.yaml as well.